Why are the debugger and the code contradicting?
I am trying to make a bomberman style game in assembly language. In this game I have a fixed map made up from '*, spaces and 'b. To move the players I have created two byte-type variables called player1 and player2, that store the current position of the players (up to 250). When you enter a valid input, the corresponding movement function will activate and load in the register b the position of said player, decrement it or decrement it depending on the movement and leave a trace in the position it currently is ('.' for p1 and ',' for p2) which doesn't work either due to the same problem.
Then it calls to validate the movement, in x i have the direction of the first digit of the map, and in b the position of the player, so why does lda b,x not work properly? The positions work just fine, bu that statement sometimes returns in a ascii codes of characters that aren't even in the text. The best part is that when I do the instruction manually (adding the b register to the x direction) and examine that memory with the debugger it shows me the correct character. Why could this be happening?

This is the entire code, the relevant subrutine is "validate_pos"
            .area PROG (ABS)

    keyboard     .equ 0xFF02
    screen    .equ 0xFF00

    b1:         .byte 57       
    b2:         .byte 70
    b3:         .byte 141
    b4:         .byte 155
    b5:         .byte 216
    m:          .byte 19
    player1:    .byte 96  
    player2:    .byte 80


    statep1:   .byte 1    ;0-exploted, 1-playing, 2-goal
    statep2:   .byte 1
    turn:      .byte 0    ;0-P1, 1-P2
    statemap: .byte 0    ;0-no_bombs, 1-w_bombs


                .org 0x100
                .globl begin

    menu:       .ascii "\n\n\n\n\n----------------------------------------------"
                .ascii "\n-            Bomberman                  -"
                .ascii "\n----------------------------------------------"
                .ascii "\nModo de juego: player 1- W,A,S,D             "
                .ascii "\n               player 2- I,K,J,L             "
                .ascii "\n                                              "
                .ascii "\To exit the program press 'p' at any"
                .ascii "\nmoment.                                      "
                .ascii "\nTo show the hidden bombs press 'b' at        "
                .ascii "\any moment.                            "
                .ascii "\n----------------------------------------------"
                .asciz "\n to begin press 'b':"
            
    goal1:      .asciz "\n\33[31mplayer 1\33[37m: goal!"
    goal2:      .asciz "\n\33[34mplayer 2\33[37m: goal!"
    playing1:   .asciz "\n\33[31mplayer 1\33[37m: playing..."
    playing2:   .asciz "\n\33[34mplayer 2\33[37m: playing..."   
    exploted1: .asciz "\n\33[31mplayer 1\33[37m: exploted"
    exploted2: .asciz "\n\33[34mplayer 2\33[37m: exploted!"

            
            
    t1:         .asciz "\nturn \33[31mplayer 1\33[37m: (W,A,S,D...b...p): "
    t2:         .asciz "\nturn \33[34mplayer 2\33[37m: (I,J,K,L...b...p): "

        
            
    map :      .ascii "\n******************M*****"
                .ascii "\n*                      *"
                .ascii "\n*     b            b   *"
                .ascii "\n*                      *"
                .ascii "\n*                      *"
                .ascii "\n*              b       *"
                .ascii "\n*   b                  *"
                .ascii "\n*                      *"
                .ascii "\n*              b       *"
                .asciz "\n************************"
            
    wins1:      .asciz "\nwins PLAYER 1!"
    wins2:      .asciz "\nwins PLAYER 2!"


    begin:
        ldu 0xf000
        lbsr read_menu  

    program:
            clra
            clrb
            lbsr siguiente_turn
            lbsr validate_input
            lbsr pmap
            
            
    finish: clra
            sta 0xFF01
            
    read_menu:
        ldx #menu
        lbsr loop
        lda keyboard
        cmpa #'b
        lbeq begin_program
        cmpa #'p
        lbeq finish1  
        bra begin   
    begin_program:
        clra
        lda #'0    
        sta statemap 
        lbsr pmap
        clra
        rts
    finish1:
        clra
        sta 0xFF01
    
    exit1:
        clra
        bra program
    pmap:   
        clra    
        clrb    
        ldx #map
        lda statemap
        cmpa #'0
        beq no_bombs
        cmpa #'1
        beq w_bombs
    w_bombs:
        lda ,x+
        beq exit1
        cmpb player1
        beq is_1
        cmpb player2
        beq is_2
        sta screen
        incb
        bra w_bombs
    no_bombs:
        lda ,x+
        beq exit1
        cmpb player1
        beq is_1
        cmpb player2
        beq is_2
        cmpa #'b
        beq is_b
        sta screen
        incb
        bra no_bombs
    is_1:
        lda #'1
        sta screen
        incb
        clra
        lda statemap
        cmpa #'0
        beq no_bombs
        cmpa #'1
        beq w_bombs
    is_2:
        lda #'2
        sta screen
        incb
        clra
        lda statemap
        cmpa #'0
        beq no_bombs
        cmpa #'1
        beq w_bombs 
    is_b:
        lda #' 
        sta screen
        incb
        bra no_bombs

    siguiente_turn:  
            clra
            lda turn
            cmpa #'0
        lbeq p1
            cmpa #'1
        lbeq p2
        
    p1:     
        lbsr imprimir_state
            ldx #t1
            lbsr loop
            rts

    p2:     
        lbsr imprimir_state 
        ldx #t2
            lbsr loop
            rts    
    imprimir_state:
        lbsr pstate1
        lbsr pstate2
        rts
    pstate1:
        clrb
            ldb statep1
            cmpb #0
        lbeq e1
            cmpb #1
        lbeq j1
            cmpb #2
        lbeq m1
            clrb
    pstate2:      
            ldb statep2
            cmpb #0
        lbeq e2
            cmpb #1
        lbeq j2
            cmpb #2
        lbeq m2
            clrb
            
    e1:     ldx #exploted1
            lbsr loop
            rts
    e2:     ldx #exploted2
            lbsr loop
            rts
    j1:     ldx #playing1
            lbsr loop
            rts
    j2:     ldx #playing2
            lbsr loop
            rts
    m1:     ldx #goal1
            lbsr loop
            rts
    m2:     ldx #goal2
            lbsr loop
            rts                  
    validate_input:
        lda keyboard
        ldb turn   
        ldx #map       
        cmpb #'0
        lbeq validate_input_p1 
        cmpb #'1
        lbeq validate_input_p2 
        clrb
    validate_input_p1:
        cmpa #'w
        lbeq move_up_p1 
        cmpa #'a
        lbeq move_left_p1
        cmpa #'s
        lbeq move_down_p1
        cmpa #'d
        lbeq move_right_p1
        cmpa #'b
        lbeq changeb       
        cmpa #'p
        lbeq finish2        
        lbsr program
        rts
    validate_input_p2:
        cmpa #'i
        lbeq move_up_p2
        cmpa #'j
        lbeq move_left_p2
        cmpa #'k
        lbeq move_down_p2
        cmpa #'l
        lbeq move_right_p2
        cmpa #'b
        lbeq changeb
        cmpa #'p
        lbeq finish2        
        lbsr program
        rts
    changeb:
        clra
        lda statemap
        cmpa #'0
        lbeq change1
        cmpa #'1
        lbeq change0
    change1:
        clra
        ldb #'1
        stb statemap
        lbsr pmap
        clrb
        rts
    change0:
        clra
        ldb #'0
        stb statemap
        lbsr pmap
        clrb
        rts
    exit_validate1:
        clra        
        lda #'1
        sta turn
        clra
        rts
    exit_validate2:
        clra
        lda #'0
        sta turn
        clra
        rts

    finish2:
        clra
        sta 0xFF01


    move_up_p1:
        ldb player1
        lda #'.
        sta b,x
        ldb player1
        subb #25
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player1
        lbsr exit_validate1
        rts
    move_left_p1:
        lda #'.
        sta b,x
        ldb player1
        decb
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player1
        lbsr exit_validate1
        rts
    move_right_p1:
        lda #'.
        sta b,x
        ldb player1
        incb
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player1
        jsr exit_validate1
        rts
    move_down_p1:
        lda #'.
        sta b,x 
        ldb player1
        addb #25
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player1
        lbsr exit_validate1
        rts
    move_right_p2:
        lda #',
        sta b,x
        ldb player2
        incb
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player2
        lbsr exit_validate2
        rts
    move_left_p2:
        lda #',
        sta b,x
        ldb player2
        decb
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player2
        lbsr exit_validate2
        rts
    move_up_p2:
        lda #',
        sta b,x 
        ldb player2
        subb #25
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player2
        lbsr exit_validate2
        rts
    move_down_p2:
        lda #',
        sta b,x
        ldb player2
        addb #25
        lbsr validate_pos
        stb player2

        lbsr exit_validate2
        rts
    validate_pos:
        lda b,x
        cmpb #225   
        lbhs program
        cmpb #25 
        lbls program
        cmpa #'* 
        lbeq program
        cmpa #'1
        lbeq program
        cmpa #'2
        lbeq program
        cmpa #'M
        lbeq state_goal
        cmpa #'b
        lbeq state_exploted

        rts
    state_exploted:
        ldb #0
        lda turn
        cmpa #1
        lbeq goal_2
        stb statep1
        lbra exit_validate1
    exploted_2:
        sta statep2
        lbra exit_validate2
    state_goal:
        ldb #2 
        lda turn
        cmpa #1
        lbeq goal_2
        stb statep1
        lbra exit_validate1
    goal_2:
        sta statep2
        lbra exit_validate2

    loop:  
        lda ,x+
        lbeq exit
        sta screen
        bra loop
    exit:
            rts

            .org 0xFFFE     ;RESET
            .word begin  



Try doing the "manual" thing in the program: avoid the complex addressing mode, and use several instructions to form the address, then simple indirection.  That may work or offer some clue as to what actual address is being obtained. (When you add them, don't forget that b is 8 bit and x is 16 bit.)

I don't know a simpler way of doing it, addx doesn't exist and I can't think of another way to do it. @ErikEidt

Show debugger log or screenshot where we can see registers and how you checked the memory content.

Please tag this post with the appropriate processor.

Done @Jester. "x 0x04bf" prints the content of the memory at that adress, which is the result of x+b or 0x043d + 0x82. As you can see it gives back the ascii code 0x33, which is '3'. But there are no '3's in the map.

@ErikEidt is for a motorola 6809, but i can't find the tag

Can you use leay b,x, then lda ,y?  Push & pop y if it is in use?

@ErikEidt thank you, that helps debugging, but now it's telling me that b = 0x82, x = 0x43d is 0x3bf, which is lower. I guess it is treating b as a negative number. Can I tell it to interpret it as an unsigned byte or do I have to change everything to be a word?

@ErikEidt and if I change it to words, how do I do lda x,y?

Yeah, that probably explains why it is finding 0x33, which occurs earlier in your data section.  Can you use the fully 16-bit addressing mode, leay d,y?  You'll have to set up d so that is the unsigned extension of b, which you can do by simply clearing/zeroing a.  That should also work for lda d,y, (if you clear a making d a 16-bit unsigned extension of the value in b).

Apparently, the addressing mode called "Accumulator Offset from Register", when used with an 8-bit accumulator (e.g. A,Y or B,X) treats the 8-bit accumulator as signed.  (Sadly, this is not immediately forthcoming in the documentation that I've found.)
However, if your index is in B anyway, simply clearing A makes D an unsigned 16-bit extension of the value in B, so with that clearing of A, you can use D,X addressing instead of B,X.
It would make sense to start with the leay D,X followed by lda ,Y to be sure it is computing the right address, then when sure of that should be able to go back to lda D,X.

For future readers, when you're having issues with any kind of complex addressing mode, including the many found in x86 and other processors, attempt to compute the
address into a register, then followed by using simple indirection to load/store from that address.  That can illuminate how/where the complex addressing mode is differing from your expectations.  On some processors, there is an lea instruction that will take the same addressing mode yet yield the address computed into a register, which can make debugging simpler as you can observe the computed address directly.  (For some others, you'll have to substitute adds and shifts, and if those work then you've some misunderstanding of the complex addressing mode, and if those don't work then you've probably got some bad inputs as index or base pointer.)
In fact this divide & conquer approach can also be used for debugging other things in assembly or in C, C#, Java, etc..: break complex things/statements/operations down into multiple simpler statements connected by variables or registers to illuminate the intermediate computations in the debugger.
